# Configure spring integration poller based on some event

Tags: spring, spring-integration, poller

I am using jdbc-inbound-channel-adapter to poll data from database and with a poller having fixed-rate. Now I don't want to constantly look into the database. I want to have the database change notification in place to send the notification on our application and depending on that notification/event we need to invoke the poller for retrieving data.

Can you please help me what could be the configuration for the same? It would be much helpful if we can configure an event based poller for polling the data.

Thanks in advance,
Sandip

Answer (score 1):

Pollers are based on the Spring Framework `Trigger`; you can't change the poll until the next trigger occurs.

Spring Integration provides a [Conditional Pollers](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#conditional-pollers) which allow you to ignore a poll until some condition is true. Not really event-driven, but closer to what you want.

You could also use the jdbc outbound gateway for event-driven processing.